# App to all version of android?

Tags: android

Can I create an Android app that will work on all version of Android?

If no is the answer, then I guess the solution is to create a different version of my app target a particular version such as 2.2

Guide me as I'm a newbie to Android world.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Can I create an Android app that will work on all version of Android?

Yes, you can

However, some might make their app support earlier version (like 2.2+) only because they want to use some features that were introduced in earlier version.

Others might develop two different apps, one for earlier versions and the other for the others. Even you can distinguish your app versions based on other characteristics (like one for tablets only, one for phones).

You can read this [Multiple APK Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) guide for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by setting appropriate values of `android:minSdkVersion` and `android:targetSdkVersion`. [Read the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Answer (score 1):

yes. there exist compatibility libraries that let you use the most used classes. just avoid adding things that are not supported in older versions of android